# Как раскрасить каждое слово заголовка?

Tags: html, css

Как раскрасить каждое слово заголовка h2 в разный цвет с помощью css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через css только если каждое слово обернуто в тэг

Comment: Тогда мне каждое слово внутри h2 обернуть в span? Или во что то другое?

Comment: Да, как вариант
<h2><span>Текст</span> <span>текст</span></h2>

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать с помощью такого простого `JavaScript`-а.

```js
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "orange", "olive"];
var el = document.getElementById("h")
var arr = el.innerText.split(" ");
var str = "";
var i = 0;

for (var word of arr) {
  str += ` <span style="color:${colors[i++ % colors.length]}">${word}</span>`;
}

el.innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<h2 id="h">Всем привет, с вами говорит рыжий кот!</h2>
```